# Dictionary of directories

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some paths like (simplified):
/rootFolder/subfolder_1/subsubfolder_1/

```
paths = {
    'rootFolder':'rootFolder/'
    'subFolder_1':paths[rootFolder]+'subFolder/'
    'subsubFolder_1:paths[subfolder]+'subsubFolder/'
}
```

Basically, I want a static dictionary of paths, but I also want to keep dependencies so I can make just one change in the future. I am unsure if that's doable, and if, then how? Do you have some better ideas than mine?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: what you want to do? explain.

Comment: I want static dict with some properties of remote server... kind of config file. I need to get easy access to directories i use... that is what i figured out. I could define class ofc, but i have more than one server, so getting all info from dictionary would be easy and neat

Comment: what's static dict?

Comment: There is no such thing in python... I meant that would be cool if there is no extra action when it's used, but nvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions as values for the keys. Because functions are not called before the `dict` is constructed, there'll be no `NameError`.

```
In [320]: paths = { 'root': lambda: '/', 'usr': lambda: os.path.join(paths['root'](), 'usr')}

In [321]: paths['root']()
Out[321]: '/'

In [322]: paths['usr']()
Out[322]: '/usr'

In [323]: paths['root'] = lambda: '//'

In [324]: paths['usr']()
Out[324]: '//usr'
```

If you don't want do `paths['root']()`, simply subclass `dict`.

```
from types import FunctionType
import os

class DynDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return val() if type(val) is FunctionType else val

paths = DynDict(root='/', tmp=lambda: os.path.join(paths['root'], 'tmp'))
print(paths['root'], paths['tmp'])
paths['root'] = '/var/'
print(paths['root'], paths['tmp'])
```

Output;

```
/ /tmp
/var/ /var/tmp
```

Comment: Seems like an answer :) Could you pls tell me what lambda is in this code?

Comment: `lambda` makes a function but the limitations are only expression are allowed in the body

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function to return the dictionary that you want.

```
def path_dict(root):
    return {'rootFolder':root,
            'subFolder_1':root+'subFolder/'
            'subsubFolder_1:root+'subfolder/subsubFolder/'
           }
```

Then,

```
>>> path_dict('rootFolder/')
{'subsubfolder_1': 'rootFolder/subfolder/subsubfolder/', 'rootFolder': 'rootFolder/', 'subfolder_1': 'rootFolder/subfolder/'}
```

If you want to use keys in the dictionary to build off of, you can do it by initializing the dictionary in several steps.

```
paths = {'rootFolder':'rootFolder/'}
paths['subFolder_1'] = paths['rootFolder']+'subFolder/'
```

It is not a one-line instantiation of the directory, but you can combine the two to have a one-line instantiation with less code reuse.

```
def path_dict(root):
    paths = {'rootFolder':root}
    paths['subFolder_1'] = paths['rootFolder']+'subFolder/'
    paths['subsubFolder_1'] = paths['subFolder_1']+'subsubFolder/'

    return paths
```

Comment: this is an idea, but a root is a param, so only it can be used as variable. As you see, you couldn't use subfolder_1 for 'subsubFolder_1 initialization. Yet I can use a method to create those paths, then create a dictionary and return it - I just thought there is easier way to do that.
I cannot use inside key for creating another one, can I?

Comment: See my edit for using the keys to generate a dictionary. I am not sure you can do it in one step, but you can reduce code reuse at least...

Comment: I mean, I can initialize this directories, and then 'convert' them into dictionary, but that is just redundant action then. I can access those directories anyway, so there is no need of having dictionary at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
paths = {
  'rootFolder'    :  "'rootFolder/'",
  'subFolder_1'   :  "eval(paths['rootFolder']) + 'subFolder/'",
  'subsubFolder_1':  "eval(paths['subFolder_1'])+ 'subsubFolder/'"
}
```

access via:

```
eval(paths["subsubFolder_1"])
# 'rootFolder/subFolder/subsubFolder/'
```

you can encapsulate the eval-usage by a function getPath("keyInDict") which do the user-unfriendly part of accessing the dict

Comment: why `eval` two times?

Comment: it is a recursive definition as every path["..."] is evaluated in the call stack. Otherwise, we would end up with a string like "paths['rootFolder']+'subFolder/'"

Comment: Nice workaround, still to use it the second eval needs to be made, which is  highly user unfriendly :P

Comment: you don't need `eval` in the value.

Comment: i don't need eval in the value only for depth = 1. Try to evaluate path["subsubFolder_1"]  (path-depth > 1) without eval in the value.